# MVC WebGrid Conditional Concate Htlm.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid, html.actionlink

I'm trying to concatenate 2 Html.ActionLink in a conditionnal column in a WebGrid.
somethings like that :

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns:grid.Columns(
   grid.Column("AccountNumber"),
   grid.Column("ContractNumber"),
   grid.Column("DisplayName"),
   grid.Column("IsFinalized"," ",format:(item) => (item.IsFinalized == true) 
     ?@<text> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber}) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber }) </text>
     :@<text> @Html.ActionLink("Validate", "Validate", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber} | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber }))</text>)
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If found the solution using:

```
 new HtmlString()
```

so this:

```
grid.Column("IsFinalized"," ",format:(item) => (item.IsFinalized == true) 
     ?@<text> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber}) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber }) </text>
     :@<text> @Html.ActionLink("Validate", "Validate", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber} | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber }))</text>)
```

gives :

```
grid.Column("IsFinalized", " ", format: item => (item.IsFinalized == true)
    ? new HtmlString( Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber }).ToString() + "|" + Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber }).ToString())
    : new HtmlString( Html.ActionLink("Validate", "Validate", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber }).ToString() + "|" + Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { accountId = item.AccountNumber }).ToString())
```